# What is Article 50?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, article-50

Former Prime Minister David Cameron said he would leave triggering Article 50 up to his successor. What exactly is Article 50?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He is talking about [Article 50 of the Treaties of the European Union](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-european-union-and-comments/title-6-final-provisions/137-article-50.html). These treaties are the constitutional base of the European Union. The article is about a country voluntarily leaving the union:

> 1. Any Member State may decide to withdraw from the Union in accordance with its own constitutional requirements.
> 2. A Member State which decides to withdraw shall notify the European Council of its intention. In the light of the guidelines provided by
>      the European Council, the Union shall negotiate and conclude an
>      agreement with that State, setting out the arrangements for its
>      withdrawal, taking account of the framework for its future
>      relationship with the Union. That agreement shall be negotiated in
>      accordance with Article 218(3) of the Treaty on the Functioning of the
>      European Union. It shall be concluded on behalf of the Union by the
>      Council, acting by a qualified majority, after obtaining the consent
>      of the European Parliament.
> 3. The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that,
>      two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless
>      the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned,
>      unanimously decides to extend this period.
> 4. For the purposes of paragraphs 2 and 3, the member of the European Council or of the Council representing the withdrawing Member State
>      shall not participate in the discussions of the European Council or
>      Council or in decisions concerning it.
>
>    A qualified majority shall be defined in accordance with Article
>      238(3)(b) of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union.
> 5. If a State which has withdrawn from the Union asks to rejoin, its request shall be subject to the procedure referred to in Article 49.

Answer (score 6):

It refers to Article 50 of the Treaty on European Union, one of two agreements which together form the [Lisbon Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Lisbon):

> The **Treaty of Lisbon** ... is an international agreement which amends the two treaties which form the constitutional basis of the European Union (EU).

[Article 50](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-European-union-and-comments/title-6-final-provisions/137-article-50.html) describes the procedure for leaving the EU:

> 1. Any Member State may decide to withdraw from the Union in accordance with its own constitutional requirements.
> 2. A Member State which decides to withdraw shall notify the European Council of its intention. In the light of the guidelines provided by the European Council, the Union shall negotiate and conclude an agreement with that State, setting out the arrangements for its withdrawal, taking account of the framework for its future relationship with the Union. That agreement shall be negotiated in accordance with Article 218(3) of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union. It shall be concluded on behalf of the Union by the Council, acting by a qualified majority, after obtaining the consent of the European Parliament.
> 3. The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned, unanimously decides to extend this period.
> 4. For the purposes of paragraphs 2 and 3, the member of the European Council or of the Council representing the withdrawing Member State shall not participate in the discussions of the European Council or Council or in decisions concerning it.
>
>    A qualified majority shall be defined in accordance with Article 238(3)(b) of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union.
> 5. If a State which has withdrawn from the Union asks to rejoin, its request shall be subject to the procedure referred to in Article 49.